# Open new email window in Outlook 2019

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-interop

I need to open a new email window in Outlook 2019 but when I run the code it does nothing ...

```
         OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

         OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `OutMail.Display()` after running the code above.